# get textLabel of selected row in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want it to draw the data I have selected in the application. for example, I want the data in row 0 to pull the data in row 1. these data are kept as follows.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell


    let deviceItem: Device = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.deviceItem = deviceItem
    cell.title.text = deviceItem.title
    cell.button.isOn = deviceItem.state

    return cell
}
```

So I want to take the device names. `cell.title.text = deviceItem.title` I want to draw the lines here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to get of selected row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let deviceItem: Device = items[indexPath.row]  
        print(deviceItem.title)     
    }
```

Comment: How do I transfer this to a text label

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve edit your question and explain clearly.